# HTML not rendering my basic three.js code

Tags: javascript, html, three.js

im a bit of a noob when it comes to three.js  and html but ive created other js files and they would import into the html page just fine but im confused why my basic box copy pasta code isnt showing up on the page. it works fine when scripting it all in html but not when import the js file in the same folder. could yall help me understand whats going on?

index.js

```js
/*import * as THREE from 'three'
const canvas=document.querySelector('.webgl')
const scene = new THREE.Scene();
const geo = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1,1,1)
const mats = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
  color:'red'
})
const boxmesh=new THREE.Mesh(geo,mats)
scene.add(boxmesh)

const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75,window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight,0.1,100)
camera.position.set(0,1,2)
scene.add(camera)
const renderer=new THREE.WebGL1Renderer({
  canvas:canvas
})
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth,window.innerHeight)
renderer.setPixelRatio(Math.min(window.devicePixelRatio,2))
renderer.shadowMap.enabled=true
renderer.gammaOutput=true
renderer.render(scene, camera)*/
import * as THREE from 'three';

// init

const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.01, 10 );
camera.position.z = 1;

const scene = new THREE.Scene();
scene.background= new THREE.Color('black')

const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 0.2, 0.2, 0.2 );
const material = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();

const mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
scene.add( mesh );

const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
renderer.setAnimationLoop( animation );
document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

// animation

function animation( time ) {

    mesh.rotation.x = .1;
    mesh.rotation.y = .1;

    renderer.render( scene, camera );

}
animation()
```

index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="learning html" content="This is learing making websites">
        <title>Learing GLTF</title>
        <script src="index.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas class="webgl"></canvas>
        ?
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using the latest versions of `three.js`(e.g. `r140`), then it's important to define an import map in your HTML. Otherwise the import `import * as THREE from 'three';` does not work. A import map is required so the bare module specifier `three` can be resolved in browsers. For testing, try it with:

```
<script type="importmap">
    {
        "imports": {
            "three": "https://unpkg.com/three@0.140/build/three.module.js"
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: So if I installed using npm and the files are in the working dir I just need to import from my local folder?

Comment: it also works just fine when i put the js code in the html script tage but not when i give the script tage src='index.js'

Comment: so it seems that its pulling from the url fine but not from local files wierdly enough

Comment: it worked i just needed the reletive file path with a / at the begining to make it work thanks